# Iterating List in Text() widget in flutter throwing error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show all the natural numbers between the two inputs provided by user into Text widget but getting the above error. Here's the Snippet of my code:

```
List<int> naturalNumber = [];  <------Initialization of natural number(in the state class)

onPressed:(){
 setState(() {

                       int X = int.parse(valueOfX.text);
                       int Y = int.parse(valueOfY.text);
                       difference = Y-X;
                       if(X>0 && Y>0 && Y-X>1 &&Y-X<50){

                         for(var i=0;i<=difference;i++){
                           naturalNumber[i] = X;
                           X=X+1;
                         }
                         for(int j=0;j<=naturalNumber.length;j++)
                         {
                           print(naturalNumber[j]);
                         }
                         shouldDisplay = !shouldDisplay;

                       }
}
}
```

**Here I want to print all the natural number between user input :**

```
 shouldDisplay?Column(
                children: [
                  for ( var i in naturalNumber ) Text(i.toString())
                ],
              ):Spacer()
```

Comment: are you getting the correct output for this line                            `print(naturalNumber[j]);`

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha,  No, I'm not getting any output there as well. While earlier when I was using naturalNumber = [i], then I was able to print but only in that loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =>
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: CounterDemo()));

class CounterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterDemoState createState() => _CounterDemoState();
}

class _CounterDemoState extends State<CounterDemo> {
  var shouldDisplay = false;
  int x = 20;
  int y = 19;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Counter Demo"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text("Show Values"),
              onPressed:()=>setState(() {
                shouldDisplay = !shouldDisplay;
              }),
            ),
            shouldDisplay
                ? ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: (x - y).abs() + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                      var highestValue =x>y?x:y;
                      var lowestValue =x<y?x:y;

                      // in ascending form from 1 to 10
                      return Center(child: Text((lowestValue + index).abs().toString()));

                      // in descending form from 10 to 1
                   // return Center(child: Text((highestValue - index).abs().toString()));
                    })
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works for me. :)

Comment: Still getting the same error: "Range Error", I'm I doing anything wrong while storing data to the naturalNumber?

Comment: can you check by replacing in IF condition? (> with >= AND < with <=)

Comment: means you want something like to show value in text between random two numbers right? for example you want to see the numbers in text from X=10 to Y=1, right? like 10,9,8,7....

Comment: Yes exactly, but value of Y must be greater than X.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> numbers = getAllNaturalNumbers(5, 10);

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: numbers.length,
        itemBuilder: (_cont, _pos) => Text('${numbers[_pos]}'));
  }

  List<int> getAllNaturalNumbers(int first, int second) {
    return first > second
        ? List.generate(first - second + 1, (val) => second + val)
        : List.generate(second - first + 1, (val) => first + val);
  }
}
```